Spring Security SwitchUserFilter not working
In the Current Project I am using Spring-Security 5.0.0.RELEASE . Now I am Upgrading the Version 5.8.11 while upgrading the switch user functionality not working it not giving any error just 404 not found .
Below code is security-context file.
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthEntryPoint">
     <!-- Custom Filters and Handlers -->
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customUsernamePasswordAuthFilter"/>
    <access-denied-handler  ref="customAccessDeniedHandler"/>  
    <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" />
    <!-- End of Add other custom filters as needed -->

    <!-- Logout Configuration -->
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/Homepage?logout=true"/>

    <!-- CSRF Protection -->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>

    <!-- HTTP Headers Configuration -->
    <headers>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </headers>

    <!-- Session Management -->
    <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

    <!-- Access Denied Handling -->
    <access-denied-handler ref="customAccessDeniedHandler"/>

</http>

<b:bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">
    <b:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailService"/>
    <b:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/admin/impersonate"/>
    <b:property name="targetUrl" value="/Homepage"/>

    <b:property name="switchFailureUrl" value="/admin/switchUser"/>
</b:bean> 

I need to resolve the without changing status of CSRF
